# String array Categorizing

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, categorization

I have a string array where I want to check each element in the array with 8 other array elements to see if any of those element in the first array element categorize under any of them.

Simply I want to categorize a string array. So in order to do that I have to check with 8 other arrays (Because I have 8 categories) I want to know an efficient way to do this without looping one by one

Comment: Maybe a short (pseudo) code example would help. You are repeating like three times that you are doing something with 8 arrays, but I still didnt get the question. Thus see [mcve].

Comment: Checkout hashmaps in Java.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can sort the array and then use `Arrays.binarySearch()` method instead of looping one by one. It is more efficient way to search a particular element.

Comment: @Hasini You can only accept 1 solution per question. So you would want to accept the one which helped you most.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HashMap instead of array or arraylist.

Implement the 8 categories as HashMap. 
From the element you want to check, match it against the the 8 HashMaps. This will give you a worst case of 8 checks.

If you can combine the values of all 8 categories into one HashMap, the worst case will be 1.

I believe you could combine the values from various categories and have only 1 HashMap by appending a checksum to each value. Something like:

```
//values in the hash map
xxxx_cat1
yyyy_cat1
zzzz_cat1
xxxx_cat2
yyyy_cat2
zzzz_cat2
```

After you get the value from the HashMap, just based on the checksum (the appended text) to get its category.

Comment: Thanks this will do it

Comment: yeah sure why not. Thanks again!